# How can I get IEditorPart from ICompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have `ICompilationUnit` object.How I can to get either `file name with extension` or `IEditorPart`?

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion above will work to get you the simple name of the resource.  However, if your goal is to find an existing editor for the compilation unit, then you'd be better off doing this:

```
IEditorPart editor = org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.isOpenInEditor(unit);
```

This will return null if the unit is not opened in an editor.  If you want to open the unit if not already opened, then you should do this:

```
IEditorPart editor = org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.isOpenInEditor(unit);
```

The nice things about both of these methods is that if you pass in somthing other than an ICompilationUnit, that portion of the editor will automatically be selected.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use compUnit.getCorrespondingResource().getName() for getting the name